# wp_get_current_user() function not working in Rest API callback function

Tags: rest-api

Consider the following class.

```
<?php
class MCQAcademy_Endpoint extends WP_REST_Controller {

    /**
     * Register the routes for the objects of the controller.
     */
    public function register_routes() {
        $version = '1';
        $namespace = 'custompath/v' . $version;
        $base = 'endpointbase';

        register_rest_route(
            $namespace,
            '/' . $base,
            array(
                array(
                    'methods'         => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
                    'callback'        => array( $this, 'get_items' ),
                    'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'get_items_permissions_check' ),
                    'args'            => array(),
                )
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function get_items( $request ) {
        $rs = array(
            'data' => array(),
            'request' => array(
                'lang' => 'en',
            ),
        );

        $args = array();
        $items = get_posts( $args );

        foreach( $items as $item ) {
            $itemdata = $this->prepare_item_for_response( $item, $request );
            $rs['data'][] = $this->prepare_response_for_collection( $itemdata );
        }

        $rs['wp_get_current_user'] = wp_get_current_user(); // Does not output as expected

        return new WP_REST_Response( $rs, 200 );
    }

    /**
     * Check if a given request has access to get items
     */
    public function get_items_permissions_check( $request ) {
        return true; // to make readable by all
    }


    /**
     * Prepare the item for create or update operation
     */
    protected function prepare_item_for_database( $request ) {
        return $request;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the item for the REST response
     */
    public function prepare_item_for_response( $item, $request ) {
        $data = array(
            'ID' => $item->ID,
            'post_content' => wpautop($item->post_content),
            'post_title' => $item->post_title,
        );

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the query params for collections
     */
    public function get_collection_params() {
        return array(
            'page'     => array(
                'description'        => 'Current page of the collection.',
                'type'               => 'integer',
                'default'            => 1,
                'sanitize_callback'  => 'absint',
            ),
            'per_page' => array(
                'description'        => 'Maximum number of items to be returned in result set.',
                'type'               => 'integer',
                'default'            => 10,
                'sanitize_callback'  => 'absint',
            ),
            'search'   => array(
                'description'        => 'Limit results to those matching a string.',
                'type'               => 'string',
                'sanitize_callback'  => 'sanitize_text_field',
            ),
        );
    }

    // Register our REST Server
    public function hook_rest_server(){
        add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( $this, 'register_routes' ) );
    }
}

$myEndpoint = new MCQAcademy_Endpoint();
$myEndpoint->hook_rest_server();
```

Everything is going well except calling the `wp_get_current_user()` function in the `get_items()` function return empty user even though the user is `logged in` in the website.

Answer (score 17):

Logged in on your website doesn't mean the user is authenticated in the REST API request, that's why you are not getting the correct user or a `Id = 0`

Please take a look to the REST API authentication methods on the docs:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

> For developers making manual Ajax requests, the nonce will need to be passed with each request. The API uses nonces with the action set to wp_rest. These can then be passed to the API via the _wpnonce data parameter (either POST data or in the query for GET requests), or via the X-WP-Nonce header. If no nonce is provided the API will set the current user to 0, turning the request into an unauthenticated request, even if you’re logged into WordPress.

For remote authentication I'd recommend the JWT plugin for a quick start:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/

Or you can use the ones suggested on the docs:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins

Comment: I need user id if the user is loggedin in the site. Since the endpoint is open, no need to check permission.

Comment: This line return false always even though the user is loggedin in the website.
`$rs['wp_get_current_user'] = is_user_logged_in() ? get_current_user_id() : false;`

Comment: Hi @ShahAlom as I mentioned on my answer, website logged in is not the same as REST API logged in, please take a look to the REST API authentication methods on the docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Comment: For cookie authentication: For developers making manual Ajax requests, the nonce will need to be passed with each request. The API uses nonces with the action set to wp_rest. These can then be passed to the API via the _wpnonce data parameter (either POST data or in the query for GET requests), or via the X-WP-Nonce header. If no nonce is provided the API will set the current user to 0, turning the request into an unauthenticated request, even if you’re logged into WordPress.

Comment: Please update your answer with this last comment so that I can accept it as solution.

Comment: Even with JWT authentication, you still need to pass the X-WP-Nonce header to get the current user, in example if you need to access users/me still returns 401, same for query users by role, and so on. The "non manual" AJAX requests are "special" just because the official API client, includes that header, but nothing else.

Comment: @JesúsFranco from my experience using the JWT plugin, there is no need to send any addition header, just the Authorization header with the previous generated token for authentication, `/wp/v2/users/me` works for me

Comment: Hmmm, that makes me think what could be different from setup to setup, the version of the plugin? Of the core?

Comment: Thinking on what the differences could be, I have observed two type of requests being forbidden without the use of the nonce, and allowed without it, too. The difference I've noticed is the environment of the request. Requests through a PHP script are allowed with just the Token being enough, requests through the browser are not without the nonce.

Comment: @JesúsFranco you are right, for server side requests(my case), the token will be enough, for client side/manual ajax calls, you have to include the nonce to avoid CSRF, there is no need to include the token since you already have a logged in user and client side is cookie based

Answer (score 8):

If an API call comes in that does not have a nonce set, WordPress will de-authenticate the request, killing the current user and making the request unauthenticated. This CSFR protection is automatic, and you don't have to do anything for it to work other than include the nonce.

The way to solve this is to include a nonce. Something like this:

```
$_wpnonce = wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' );
echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = '_wpnonce' value = '$_wpnonce' />";
```

And include it in your API request. The nonce must be called "_wpnonce" and the action must be "wp_rest" for the API to work. It can go in the URL or in the post body.

Answer (score 5):

To have a fully working code sample here comes a sample plugin on how to retrieve the current user's ID via REST.

**my-plugin.php**

```
class MyPlugin {

  public function __construct() {

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'scripts']);
    add_action('rest_api_init', [$this, 'rest']);
  }

  function scripts() {

    // Add JS.
    wp_enqueue_script('my-plugin', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/scripts.js', ['jquery'], NULL, TRUE);
    // Pass nonce to JS.
    wp_localize_script('my-plugin', 'MyPluginSettings', [
      'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest'),
    ]);
  }

  function rest() {

    // Register route.
    register_rest_route('my-plugin/v1', '/uid', [
      'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
      'callback' => [$this, 'rest_callback'],
    ]);
  }

  function rest_callback($data) {

    // Get current user ID.
    $data = [
      'uid' => get_current_user_id(),
    ];

    $response = new WP_REST_Response($data, 200);
    // Set headers.
    $response->set_headers(['Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store, private']);

    return $response;
  }

}

new MyPlugin();
```

**js/scripts.js**

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    var settings = MyPluginSettings;

    $.ajax({
      url: '/wp-json/my-plugin/v1/uid',
      method: 'GET',
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', settings.nonce);
      }
    }).done(function(response) {

      // Will return your UID.
      console.log(response);
    });

  });

})(jQuery);
```

---

Resource: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Comment: I do not understand how 'MyPluginSettings' is passed to script. Possible things to consider: I'm currently not using JQuery but "vanilla" JavaScript ... I was insterting my script in html <script> tags when need, but I tried including them with wp_enqueue_script and got the same issue.

Comment: I got this working, I had written some wrong path when adapting for wp_enqueue_script() . But also, I had multiple scripts, and I just understood that the first parameter of wp_enqueue_script() isn't actually specific to plug-in but is specific to script ( maybe you should change 'my-plugin' in you answer because that's confusing.

Comment: @TTT – Swap it with `my-script` for example? Yes, it just should be some unique handle name, often containing the name of the plugin or theme.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_get_current_user()` does not work because your user is not set perfectly. See below code in `/wp-includes/user.php` for reference.

```
if ( ! empty( $current_user ) ) {
    if ( $current_user instanceof WP_User ) {
        return $current_user;
    }

    // Upgrade stdClass to WP_User
    if ( is_object( $current_user ) && isset( $current_user->ID ) ) {
        $cur_id       = $current_user->ID;
        $current_user = null;
        wp_set_current_user( $cur_id );
        return $current_user;
    }

    // $current_user has a junk value. Force to WP_User with ID 0.
    $current_user = null;
    wp_set_current_user( 0 );
    return $current_user;
}

if ( defined( 'XMLRPC_REQUEST' ) && XMLRPC_REQUEST ) {
    wp_set_current_user( 0 );
    return $current_user;
}
```

All you need to do is wp_set_current_user( {user_id} ) at the start of your API.