# Is there a way to identify a user in a custom REST API method?

Tags: users, user-roles, rest-api

In a custom REST API method, I would like to identify the user (typically `get_current_user_id()` then retrieve their data from database (things like they're role and some custom permission).

But so far `get_current_user_id()` returns 0 (which is not the current user ID).

Is it possible to identify user in REST API?

Otherwise, a solution I see is using a page as "sort of" API ... but I think that would be an ugly solution.

Comment: Look at my answer at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/329992/30597 – this will only work when passing nonce to the request.

Comment: It looks like actual duplicate this time, just didn't search with the right keywords.

However I have a subquestion ... (I'm not familiar with the word "nonce", English is not my mother language) the nonce is not something that someone could forge in client side to pretend they're another user, right?

Comment: Yep, WordPress security tokens are called "nonce". See https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces

Comment: A nonce https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce is a pseudo random number used to prevent replay attacks and other security threats. It's also a word for something rather unfortunate in the UK. Authenticated REST API requests should include a nonce+cookie when sent from the browser

Answer (score 0):

I spent two days searching for a simple way without adding plugins.

first in function.php where you define your api

```
//enqueue the script which will use the api
function api_callings_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('score-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ScoreSaving.js', ['jquery'], NULL, TRUE);
    // Pass nonce to JS.
    wp_localize_script('score-script', 'ScoreSettings', [
      'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest'),
    ]);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'api_callings_scripts' );
```

Then your script Ajax call cloud be something like this

```
jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/wp-json/score/update",
      data: {"var1":"value1"},
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', ScoreSettings.nonce);
      },
    success: 
        function( data ) {
          console.log( data );
        }
    });
```

Now you can use `get_current_user_id()` inside your API code.