# Rest API code to get ID of current user not working: get_current_user_id() gives 0

Tags: users, rest-api, user-meta, authentication

#### Background

I am trying to write Rest API code to get the ID of the user who triggers the function in question. I found a fantastic answer to this exact question, that was very kindly provided by user leymaxx: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/329992/220571

#### Problem and Theories of Cause

However, when I test this code (by sending a Get request to my endpoint, using Postman), it always returns 0 when I call get_current_user_id(). I cannot figure out why it is doing this, but I have three theories:

1. **I may have implemented this wrong.** That is, although the answer provided code, it did not explain exactly where it should be placed. I also needed to add some boilerplate such as declaring a plugin. I think I have worked this out, but I could be mistaken.
2. **The Rest API may have changed since the answer was posted.** The question was from 2 years ago, so possibly there has been some subtle syntactical change due to an update.
3. **The API may not be able to detect that I am logged in.** My website is in maintenance mode, so perhaps this prevents the API from detecting that I am logged in. I logged in by clicking "Visit Site" from my WordPress Dashboard, and confirmed this worked by viewing the My Account page from within my site.

#### Question

If anyone has any ideas of where I have gone wrong, please would you let me know? If so I would very much appreciate it, and I believe that having a fully detailed answer would also help other developers who encounter this common requirement.

The details of my overall approach, and the complete code that I used are given below.

#### Overall Approach

The steps I took were as follows:

1. I created a new folder in the following location within my file management system: public_html/wp-content/plugins/example-plugin.
2. In this folder I created two files: example-plugin.php and example-script.js.
3. The code contained in these two files is shown below, and is basically identical to the above mentioned answer.

#### Code Used

The contents of example-plugin.php are as follows:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Example Plugin
* Plugin URI: https://www.example.com/
* Description: Example Description.
* Version: 1.0
* Author: John Smith
* Author URI: https://www.example.com/
**/
class MyPlugin {

  public function __construct() {

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'scripts']);
    add_action('rest_api_init', [$this, 'rest']);
  }

  function scripts() {

    // Add JS.
    wp_enqueue_script('my-plugin', 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/example-plugin/example-script.js', ['jquery'], NULL, TRUE);
    // Pass nonce to JS.
    wp_localize_script('my-plugin', 'MyPluginSettings', [
      'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest'),
    ]);
  }

  function rest() {

    // Register route.
    register_rest_route('my-plugin/v1', '/uid', [
      'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
      'callback' => [$this, 'rest_callback'],
    ]);
  }

  function rest_callback($data) {

    // Get current user ID.
    $data = [
      'uid' => get_current_user_id(),
    ];

    $response = new WP_REST_Response($data, 200);
    // Set headers.
    $response->set_headers(['Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store, private']);

    return $response;
  }

}

new MyPlugin();
```

The contents of example-script.js are as follows:

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    var settings = MyPluginSettings;

    $.ajax({
      url: '/wp-json/my-plugin/v1/uid',
      method: 'GET',
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', settings.nonce);
      }
    }).done(function(response) {

      // Will return your UID.
      console.log(response);
    });

  });

})(jQuery);
```